# Parameterisation of R::dexp

Tags: r, rcpp

I have just spent a while trying to find a bug in my code which has turned out to be an unusual (at least to me) parameterisation for the `R::dexp` function. For example:

```
cppFunction("
  double my_dexp(double x, double lambda, double is_log) {
    return R::dexp(x, lambda, is_log);
  }
")

> my_dexp(4.5, 2.5, FALSE)
[1] 0.06611956
> dexp(4.5, 2.5, FALSE)
[1] 3.251824e-05
```

Looking [here](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/html/namespaceR.html#abef82549a40bac4d41e672b8c551e0fb) I can see that they use the definition:

```
double R::dexp(double x, double sl, int lg)
```

but I haven't been able to find out what `sl` stands for. I'm not sure if this is documented anywhere - so hopefully this post stands as a warning to others who have used the function like me, and also if anyone can help as to what parameterisation has been used, and why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the function definition for `dexp`,

```
R> dexp
function (x, rate = 1, log = FALSE) 
.Call(C_dexp, x, 1/rate, log)
```

you'll see that `dexp` calls the C function `C_dexp` with parameter `1/rate`. This is what `R::dexp` is mirroring. In Rcp, they always use the same parameterisation as R itself does at the C level which may be different than the R level.

That means

```
R> my_dexp(4.5, 1/2.5, FALSE) - dexp(4.5, 2.5, FALSE)
[1] 0
```

If you look at the Wikipedia page on the [exponential function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution), you'll see the alternative parameterisation based on the reciprocal of the rate parameter, lambda. In this parameterisation, the parameter `beta=1/lambda` takes the role of a survival parameter. So the expected duration of survival of the system is `beta` units of time.